# site is not updating with out cleaning cache

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, backend, full-page-cache, websites

i want to ask my site is not updating with out cleaning cache. after any changes i have to clear the cache before it was not like that

i already try to disable cache the it's work but after disable cache my site is taking to much time to open

for example

if i change title from 
32" led {model}
32 inch led {model}

it will not take effect until i didn't clear the cache

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you write custom code or make changes to the existing code. First disable the cache from the back end. So you wont have to clear the cache each time you make the changes to the code.

Once the changes are accepted. You can enable the cache back again for better performance.

Its in the magento admin panel: **System** >> **Cache Management**

Comment: is it any possible way to after any changes cache will be clear automatically